# Custom sizing tool is not working in Canvas Drawing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6MAwT/)

HTML for Canvas:

```
<div id="canvasDiv"><canvas id="myNewCanvasColumn" width="490" height="220"></canvas></div>
```

I am working on a canvas drawing tool. Problem is that, i am unable to select the appropriate sizes for drawing. I have defined sizes like "small, normal, large and huge". Default selection is normal. I have wrote some function to determine the radius, but it is not working. Can some one help me?

Thanks a ton..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set different `context.lineWidth` to set the cursor size. I've updated the code with that.

```
function redraw() {
    clickSize.length = 0;
    context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
    //context.strokeStyle = "#df4b26";
    context.lineJoin = "round";
    //context.lineWidth = 5;                        
    for (var i = 0; i < clickX.length; i++) {
        context.beginPath();
        if (clickDrag[i] && i) {
            context.moveTo(clickX[i - 1], clickY[i - 1]);
        } else {
            context.moveTo(clickX[i] - 1, clickY[i]);
        }
        context.lineTo(clickX[i], clickY[i]);
        context.closePath();
        context.strokeStyle = clickColor[i];
        context.lineWidth = cursorSize;
        //alert('radius is'+context.lineWidth)
        context.stroke();
    }
}
$('#choosesmall').click(function () {
    curSize = "small";
    cursorSize = 1;
});
$('#choosenormal').click(function () {
    curSize = "normal";
    cursorSize = 3;
});
$('#chooselarge').click(function () {
    curSize = "large";
    cursorSize = 5;
});
$('#choosehuge').click(function () {
    curSize = "huge";
    cursorSize = 7;
});
```

See the [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6MAwT/1/)

**Edit**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    /* Declaration global Variables */
    var clickX = new Array();
    var clickY = new Array();
    var clickDrag = new Array();
    var paint;
    var context;
    var canvas;
    var colorPurple = "#cb3594";
    var colorGreen = "#659b41";
    var colorYellow = "#ffcf33";
    var colorBrown = "#986928";
    var colorRed = "#ff0000";
    var curColor = colorPurple;
    var clickColor = new Array();
    var clickSize = new Array();
    var curSize = 1;
    /* End of Declaring Global Variables */

    context = document.getElementById('myNewCanvasColumn').getContext("2d");
    var canvasDiv = document.getElementById('canvasDiv');
    canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.setAttribute('width', 700);
    canvas.setAttribute('height', 300);
    canvas.setAttribute('id', 'canvas');
    canvasDiv.appendChild(canvas);
    if (typeof G_vmlCanvasManager != 'undefined') {
        canvas = G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(canvas);
    }
    var radius;
    var i = 0;
    context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    /* Event Handlers for drawing */
    $('#canvas').mousedown(function (e) {
        var mouseX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
        var mouseY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
        paint = true;
        addClick(e.pageX - this.offsetLeft, e.pageY - this.offsetTop);
        redraw();
    });
    $('#canvas').mousemove(function (e) {
        if (paint) {
            addClick(e.pageX - this.offsetLeft, e.pageY - this.offsetTop, true);
            redraw();
        }
    });
    $('#canvas').mouseup(function (e) {
        paint = false;
    });
    $('#canvas').mouseleave(function (e) {
        paint = false;
    });
    $("#clear").click(function () {
        clearDrawing();
    });
    /* End of Event Handlers */


    /* Custom Color Pickers */
    $('#choosegreen').click(function () {
        curColor = "#659b41";
    });
    $('#choosepurple').click(function () {
        curColor = "#cb3594";
    });
    $('#chooseyellow').click(function () {
        curColor = "#ffcf33";
    });
    $('#choosebrown').click(function () {
        curColor = "#986928";
    });
    $('#choosered').click(function () {
        curColor = "#ff0000";
    });
    /* End of Custom Color Pickers */

    /* Custom Size Picker */
    $('#choosesmall').click(function () {
        curSize = 1;
    });
    $('#choosenormal').click(function () {
        curSize = 3;
    });
    $('#chooselarge').click(function () {
        curSize = 5;
    });
    $('#choosehuge').click(function () {
        curSize = 7;
    });
    /* End of Custom Size Picker */
    function addClick(x, y, dragging) {
        clickX.push(x);
        clickY.push(y);
        clickDrag.push(dragging);
        clickColor.push(curColor);
        clickSize.push(curSize);
        //        alert(clickSize);
    }

    function clearDrawing() {
        clickX.length = 0;
        clickY.length = 0;
        clickDrag.length = 0;
        context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
    }

    function redraw() {
        context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
        //context.strokeStyle = "#df4b26";
        context.lineJoin = "round";
        //context.lineWidth = 5;                        
        for (var i = 0; i < clickX.length; i++) {

            context.beginPath();

            if (clickDrag[i] && i) {
                context.moveTo(clickX[i - 1], clickY[i - 1]);
            } else {
                context.moveTo(clickX[i] - 1, clickY[i]);
            }
            context.lineTo(clickX[i], clickY[i]);
            context.closePath();
            context.strokeStyle = clickColor[i];
            context.lineWidth = clickSize[i];
            // alert(clickColor[i]);
            //alert('radius is'+context.lineWidth)
            context.stroke();
        }
    }
});
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6MAwT/3/)

Comment: Thank you, checked ur code. But there is an issue. It is that, the radius size is changing simultaneously, when you prefer to go with other sizing tool, for an already drawn image...

Comment: Works fine now... Accepted :)